# What variable will let me access user profile info?

Tags: 7, users

I'm using prepopulate to prepopulate a feild of a `node/add/content`. I'm trying to generate a URL using some PHP code that willl generate a URL like:

```
http://mysite.com/node/add/content_type?edit[title]={$some_var}
```

Each of my user profiles will have this link at the top of the page and I would like `$some_var` to hold the username of the user whos profile we are currently viewing. I was wonder how to populate `$some_var` with the username of the user profile being viewed.

Something like:

```
$some_var = $username;
print("<a href=\"http://mysite.com/node/add/content_type?edit[title]={$some_var}\">Content Type</a>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this link is to be on the user profile page then you can grab the related user ID from the internal URL (using the [`arg()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) function), and then use [`user_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load/7) to load a user object that contains the username:

```
// Get user ID from internal router path (this isn't necessarily the URL shown in the address bar, it's the internal path that Drupal is using to serve the page).
$uid = arg(1);

// Load the user account and extract the username
$account = user_load($uid);
$username = $account->name;
```

Comment: works perfectly!